# How to modify the drupal search templates?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-themes, drupal-templates

I'm attempting to create my own templates for the search pages using drupal 6.  When creating these template pages i usually use [Drupal Template Suggests](http://drupal.org/node/190815#template-suggestions) but for some reason when creating the files:

search-block-form.tpl.php
search-result.tpl.php
search-results.tpl.php
search-theme-form.tpl.php

None of them seem to override the Drupal templates for some reason? is there anything special that i have to put in or anything i can test to see if they are working as everything i've tried so far has failed to work :/

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**

Seems they work now i've got these working:

search-result.tpl.php
search-results.tpl.php

But it seems i can't get hold of the template that controls the form...any ideas which one that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

search-theme-form.tpl.php: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search-theme-form.tpl.php/6

You can customize some of the form with the preprocessor: http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_search_theme_form/6

Here's an example of using the preprocessor: http://agaric.com/note/theme-search-form-drupal-6

Comment: Broken link, any recent examples?

Answer (score 0):

Place it to your current theme folder, after refresh browser. May be clearing cache required, if you enable caching.
See internal descriptions of these files here: http://api.drupal.org/api/search/6/search

Comment: The theme registry is always on, even if page caching is disabled. So if you add new templates to your theme, you always have to rebuild the theme registry.