# Determine if the current Drupal page is a search results page?

Tags: drupal

How can I determine if the current Drupal page is a search results page?

Comment: Please give some more information about what you want to do. And are you creating a module or working in templates?

Comment: Look at this post for information about how to edit the template. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068996/how-to-modify-the-drupal-search-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming clean URLs are on, this usually works

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page (&$vars, $hook) {
  // ...  

  if ($hook == 'page' && arg(0) == 'search') {
    // do search related stuff
  }
}
```

inside your `template.php`.

Normal template suggestions work, too, such as using a `page-search.tpl.php` instead of `page.tpl.php` if that is also needed.

Comment: The arg() function does not rely on clean URLs, so this will also work when clean URLs are disabled. 

The $hook variable is only available in MYTHEME_preprocess(&$vars, $hook). The function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) is already specific to the 'page' hook, so there is not $hook variable there and you can leave it out of the if-statement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on arg(); I never deploy w/o clean URLs.  Also thanks for pointing out the preprocess error, I never noticed that (this is how it is in the zen STARTERKIT).